# How do I access specific nodes in a xml structure via php?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to parse an xml string `$content`, which has following structure:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">269</int></lst>
</response>
```

I am interested in the two `int` fields (here with the values `0` and `269`).

I load the xml via:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
```

I then expected that:

```
$fields = $xml->xpath('int');
```

would give me an array of those fields, alas, it is empty.

What am I doing wrong? How can I parse the int fields in this example?

Answer (score 2):

you forget slashes

```
$fields = $xml->xpath('//int');
```

also

```
$status= $xml->xpath('//int[@name="status"]');
$QTime= $xml->xpath('//int[@name="QTime"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$xml ='<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">269</int></lst>
</response>';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);

echo $field = $xml->lst->int[0];
echo $fields = $xml->lst->int[1];
```

For attributes:-

```
echo $attr1 = $xml->lst->int[0]->attributes();
echo $attr2 = $xml->lst->int[1]->attributes();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your xpath expression little bit like that :

```
$fields = $xml->xpath('lst/int');
```

This will return complete array with node value and attribute name value. Then you can fetch them like :

```
$fields[0]->{0} AND $fields[1]->{0}
```